# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause -- Ordering an associated record with "includes" Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, include

I have an app where I show posts by a current user (posts.current_user). I would like to show the most posts that have been most recently commented on by ordering by comment.date.  It doesn't seem to want to do that...I keep getting:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "comment"

My Controller

```
 def_index
 @posts = current_user.posts.includes(:comment).order("comment.date ASC").includes(:image)
 end
```

I have tried joins and includes an I can't seem to crack this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
 @posts = current_user.posts.joins(:comment).order("comments.date ASC").includes(:image)
```

Explanation:

- you need a join
- in the order you must reference the table's name, not the association's name

Comment: I get this: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "comment"
LINE 1: ...id" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY comment.d...

Comment: ah...wait...I missed the 's' in comments! That was it.  Thank you!

Comment: "in the order you must reference the table's name, not the association's name" huge point, thanks!